# No working "up" method in migrate Codeigniter 3 with PHP8

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration, class-method, php-8

I just started working with CodeIgniter 3, I understand that it is already outdated, but the task is set to work with it. And I immediately had a problem, rummaged through the Internet and did not find an answer.

It seems to me that I am just missing a small detail. Please help guide me on the true path.

**Migration**:

```
class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => TRUE,
            ),
       ));
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
   }
```

**Migrate.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('migration');

        if (!$this->migration->version(1))
        {
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        }
    }
```

**migration.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['migration_enabled'] = TRUE;

$config['migration_type'] = 'sequential';

$config['migration_table'] = 'migrations';


$config['migration_auto_latest'] = FALSE;

$config['migration_version'] = 1;


$config['migration_path'] = APPPATH.'migrations/';
```

My Error:

> The migration class "Migration_Add_blog" is missing an "up" method.

[image]

Comment: Your code seems correct. I would look into the current migration number and change  `if ($this->migration->current() === FALSE){ show_error($this->migration->error_string());  }` not the version one, maybe the migration is past 1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this problem, we had to go a little deeper into the parent class called 'CI_Migration'.
I have php8.0, it worked incorrectly with the default Codeigniter 3.2.0-dev setting exactly the line:

```
elseif ( ! is_callable(array($class, $method)))
```

in file system/libraries/Migration.php

But in version 3.1.0 this line looks like this.

```
elseif ( ! in_array($method, array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods($class))))
```

And it was this option that worked.

Comment: so the php 8 was a condition :)

Comment: Does the same error also happens for PHP 7?